# Null reference issue occurs when converting from Domain model to View model

Tags: c#, model, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, domain-model

The below code throws null reference exception when there is no data to be returned from the stored procedure. Method executes successfully if data is present.

Am I doing anything wrong with the below code? Do I need to create an object from the model?

```
public PersonVM GetStaff()
{
    PersonDM personDM = _Repo.GetStaff();
    PersonVM personVM = PersonVM.ToViewModel(personDM);
    return personVM;
}

public class PersonDM
{
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonVM
{
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static PersonVM ToViewModel(PersonDM model)
    {
        return new PersonVM
        {
            RoleID = model.RoleID,
            Name = model.Name
        };
    }

    public PersonDM ToEntityModel()
    {
        return new PersonDM
        {
            RoleID=this.=RoleID,
            Name = this.Name,
        }
    }
}
```

When there is no data to be returned from the SP `personDM` becomes NULL. I need it to be filled with null values without returning NULL. Is it possible to achieve?

[image]

I did the same thing with a method which is returning a `List<PersonVM>` with the below code. It fills the VM with NULL values if there is no data present. How can apply the below code to a method which is returning the type `PersonVM`

```
public List<PersonVM> GetPartyByPartyRelationship(int partyRoleId, int partyRelationshipTypeId)
    {
        List<PersonDM> personDMList = _partyManagerRepo.GetPartyByPartyRelationship(partyRoleId, partyRelationshipTypeId);
        List<PersonVM> personVMList = new List<PersonVM>();
        foreach (PersonDM personDM in personDMList)
        {
            personVMList.Add(PersonVM.ToViewModel(personDM));
        }

        return personVMList;
    }
```

Comment: Where does the NullReferenceException get thrown?

Comment: Does `PersonDM personDM = _Repo.GetStaff();` actually return a PersonDM?

Comment: @ChrisPickford I have modified the question. Please have a look

Comment: @StephenWilson I have modified the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `_Repo.GetStaff()` is returning null and therefore `personDM` is null, it should not be a surprise that a `NullReferenceException` is being thrown as you're trying to access object properties within `ToViewModel()` on a null reference.

Add a null check, either in `GetStaff()` or `ToViewModel()` and handle appropriately. Based on your update, you say you want to return a viewmodel with null properties, which you can do with the null check:

```
public static PersonVM ToViewModel(PersonDM model)
{
    if (model == null)
        return new PersonVM();

    return new PersonVM
    {
        RoleID = model.RoleID,
        Name = model.Name
    };
}
```

**Update** - Or, change your `ToViewModel()` method to utilise the null-progagating operator:

```
public static PersonVM ToViewModel(PersonDM model)
{
    return new PersonVM
    {
        RoleID = model?.RoleID,
        Name = model?.Name
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want to return NULL value if the model is empty. I just want to fill the model with NULL values. I have modified the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Updated answer, use null-propagating operator - or move null check to `ToViewModel()`.

Comment: Did you mean this -> public int? RoleID { get; set; } Because -> RoleID = model?.PartyRoleID, returns a syntax error

Comment: Yes, you'll need to change your property value types to `Nullable<>`s if you want them to be null.